# Adding screenshot after every step in cucumber report using java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to add screenshot after every step in cucumber report , as of now after hooks is working fine but this is going to take screenshot of last step failed , is there a way in java selenium + cucumber where i can take the screenshot after every step in gherkin scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

***Basically you would need to have a helper method for taking screen shot after every step like below -***

```
class Utility{

public static Scenario message;    

public static void takeScreenShotAfterEveryStep() {
        byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)DriverManager.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        message.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
}
```

*Calling above method, totally depends how you have implemented framework and one of the way could be passing scenario reference from @Before method() of Cucumber hook*

```
@Before
    public void setUpScenario(Scenario scenario){
    Utility.message = scenario; 
}
```

*Then after every step have a call to takeScreenShotAfterEveryStep()*

Comment: Actually this worked , thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I think [after step](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#afterstep) hook is answer for your question.

Comment: Hi Zdadco, Thanks for the reply , i tried this @AfterStep , but i was not able to find this annotation , am using   <dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.5</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: info.cukes is old version. Use [io.cucumber:cucmber-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java) or [io.cucumber:cucmber-java8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8) they have many useful features and very easy to understand [doc](https://docs.cucumber.io/installation/java/)

Comment: This is good actually , but there are lot changes needs to be done to the existing frame work :(

Comment: I think with info.cukes lib you can use only @After with the Scenario method parameter to handle scenario completion or fail. If you still really want to take a screenshots, then you need to create a method and add it to the end of each step. I think this is the only answer to your question.

Comment: Understood , thanks for the help !!

Comment: @Rahul Perhaps you will be helped by an answer with a aspectj to a question that is marked by a moderator.